# TCPDF: why "generate pdf" button shows the same data even when different cell's button is clicked?

Tags: php, ajax, pdf, tcpdf

I am displaying data using `DataTable`, each cell has "Edit, Delete, Generate PDF". Functions of Add, Edit and Delete using Ajax are working fine. The "Generate PDF" when clicked, it opens in a new tab with data of the clicked cell's button. However, when I click on the other buttons it always show the data of the first cell, even though the URL contains that cell's id

How can I transfer data to PDF based on the button click?

```
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$data = [];

$filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $sub_array = [];
    $sub_array[] = $row["cccEmployee"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["irNumber"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["caseType"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["caseLocation"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["startDateTime"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["endDateTime"];
    // $sub_array[] = $row["caseDesc"];
    // $sub_array[] = $row["actionsTaken"];
    // $sub_array[] = $row["caseDetails"];
    // $sub_array[] = $row["caseNotes"];
    // $sub_array[] = $row["caseRecommendation"];
    
    $sub_array[] = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" name="update" class="update_report" title="Edit" id="'.$row["id"] .'">
                         <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                    </a>';
    $sub_array[] = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" name="delete" class="delete_report" title="Delete" id="'.$row["id"] .'">
                         <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                    </a>';
    $sub_array[] = '<a href="/test-pdf/'.$row['id'].'" target="_blank" id="'.$row["id"] .'">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger generate_pdf" name="generate_pdf" id="generate_pdf" value="Generate PDF"/>
                    </a>'; // This is the code for the PDF.

    $data[] = $sub_array;
}

$output = [
    "draw" => intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "recordsTotal" => $filtered_rows,
    "recordsFiltered" => get_total_reports(),
    "data" => $data,
];

echo json_encode($output);
```

**generate-pdf-report.php:**

```
include('./TCPDF/tcpdf.php');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM cases_reports";

    $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();

    while( $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $reportId = $row['id'];
        $cccEmployee = $row['cccEmployee'];
    }
    
    // Define the variables

    ob_start();
    // make TCPDF object
    $pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);

    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator('Mushref'); // $cccEmployee
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Abdulrahman Mushref'); // $cccEmployee
    $pdf->SetTitle("IR Number here"); // $caseType + $irNumber
    $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
    $pdf->SetKeywords("Case, PDF, report, 'caseType'"); // $caseType

    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();

    // Remove default header/footer
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

    // set some text to print
    $content = '';
    $content .= '  
      <div>
        <h4 align="center"> TEST '.$reportId.'</h4>
        <h4 align="center"> Employee Name: '.$cccEmployee.'</h4>

      ';  
    $content .= '</div>';  
    $pdf->writeHTML($content);  

    //Close and output PDF document
    ob_end_clean();
    $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');
```

I am using This library for routing, check for /test-pdf as it's the url to the TCPDF code.

```
// FOR TESTING
get('/test-pdf', '/backend/reports/generate-pdf-report.php');
get('/test-pdf/$report_id', '/backend/reports/generate-pdf-report.php');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the variable to the PDF generator PHP file and also, in PDF generation file $row['id'] is not used, that is the reason you are getting the same data.

Change in few places will make things work as expected.

Pass the $row['id'] value to the php file.

```
$sub_array[] = '
<a href="/test-pdf/rid/'.$row['id'].'" target="_blank" id="'.$row["id"] .'">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger generate_pdf" name="generate_pdf" id="generate_pdf" value="Generate PDF"/>
</a>'; // This is the code for the PDF.

get('/test-pdf/rid/$rid', '/backend/reports/generate-pdf-report.php');
```

And then inside the php file use it.

```
$id = $_GET['rid'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM cases_reports WHERE `id`= ?";
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->bind_param("s", $id);
...
```

Comment: Nice, but I got these errors: 

Warning: `include_once(C:/xampp/htdocs//backend/reports/generate-pdf-report.php?rid=$report_id): failed to open stream: No error in C:\xampp\htdocs\router.php on line 51`
<br/>
`Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'C:/xampp/htdocs//backend/reports/generate-pdf-report.php?rid=$report_id' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\router.php on line 51`

Comment: Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: This is a different issue, my answer was related to your question that you posted, if you were able to test that earlier then this should work fine. The problem can be solved though, if you provide how your routing works and how it handles parameters passing.

Comment: I use this for routing: https://phprouter.com/

Comment: Shouldn't I change anything for generate pdf button? `$sub_array[] = '<a href="/test-pdf/'.$row['id'].'" target="_blank" id="'.$row["id"] .'">Generate pdf</a>'; // This is the code for the PDF.`

Comment: I have updated my answer as per PHP router dynamic routing policy, take a look. Reference documentation here https://phprouter.com/get-dynamic-routes

Comment: I thank you very much for your effort, but I keep getting this error `Undefined index: rid in C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\reports\generate-pdf-report.php on line 5`. How do I define it even though I used this: `$id = $_GET['rid'];`?

Comment: I tried doing this: `$id = isset($_GET['rid']) ? $_GET['rid'] : '';` but then I get PDO error `Invalid parameter number`

Comment: Ok, I got it to work! Thank you very much